# Loading only appears at the end of code execution

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a button that erases records from a sqlite table. I tried to put loading screen but it just appears at the end. Can you help me?

```
btnImportar.Click += delegate
{
    UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Aguarde...", MaskType.Black);

    string stm = "DELETE FROM Trender";

    using (SqliteCommand cmd2 = new SqliteCommand(stm, con))
    {
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you are obstructing the UI thread for the show event to be handled. Execute the SQL on another thread, maybe use async/await.

Comment: Do it on a background thread!

Comment: Is there no "hide" after the command is finished on purpose?

Comment: @Fildor how to do this?

Comment: Sorry, deleted my answer. Did not take into account that this is xamarin.android. There seem to be some quirks to that and I don't work on xamarin, so I cannot try it out :(

Comment: @FreakyAli how to do this?

Comment: you can check this i guess https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/127213/how-to-display-loading-symbol-in-xamarin-android-ios-and-uwp

Comment: @FreakyAli not working...

Comment: Are you using native Xamarin Android?

Comment: @FreakyAli yes.

Comment: @BrunoGomes read about the multithreading!

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
btnImportar.Click += delegate
 {
  UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Aguarde...", MaskType.Black);
  Task.Run(()=> {
       string stm = "DELETE FROM Trender";
       using (SqliteCommand cmd2 = new SqliteCommand(stm, con))
         {
          cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
      });

 }
```

Comment: @BrunoGomes still appears at the end ?

Comment: @BrunoGomes try the above modifications again

Comment: @BrunoGomes i test on my side with a delay in the Task,it works like       `Task.Run(()=> {

                   Thread.Sleep(5000);
                   UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
               });`

Comment: @BrunoGomes you could refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42995472/10768653),put it on the UI thread and have a  try

Answer (score 1):

I think you are holding back the UI thread from updating. Do something like,

```cs
UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Aguarde...", MaskType.Black);

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => {
    string stm = "DELETE FROM Trender";

    using (SqliteCommand cmd2 = new SqliteCommand(stm, con))
    {
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    Activity.RunOnUiThread(() => {
        // Dismiss the dialog
    })
})
```

Comment: How do you know that it appears at the end? Does the query take long to run?

Comment: When the query ends, loading appears

Comment: Does the query take a long time to run? Because you might be just thinking that the dialog appears after. In my experience most dialogs take a couple of milliseconds to appear (especially because of animations). And if the query ends before that you might be just thinking that the dialog appears after.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like the following:

```
btnImportar.Click += button_Click;

private async void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Aguarde...", MaskType.Black);

    await DeleteContent();
}

private async Task DeleteContent()
{
    string stm = "DELETE FROM Trender";
    using (SqliteCommand cmd2 = new SqliteCommand(stm, con))
    {
        await cmd2.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btnImportar.Click += delegate
 {
UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Aguarde...", MaskType.Black);
 Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
string stm = "DELETE FROM Trender";

using (SqliteCommand cmd2 = new SqliteCommand(stm, con))
{
   await  cmd2.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
} 
 });
}
```